# Make Wordpress Pages's Titles readonly

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a WP function that add the Read-only parameter to all Pages's Titles's input, that will make the Page's title unalterable.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to have your title's read only?

Comment: It will be useful to avoid possible  mistakes. The final result is for someone else use, someone without any experience with WP, so...

Comment: that makes no sense, you would like a CMS that is no CMS at all? Just tell your client not to edit the title field. Works for me everyday.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto Let me know if my solution helps or if you have trouble implementing it.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto See my updated answer, which will restrict the script to the page edit screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished with some simple JavaScript/jQuery. Create a file called admin_title_disable.js, and queue it up within functions.php. For example:

functions.php:

```
wp_register_script('admin_title_disable', '/path/to/admin_title_disable.js');
function disableAdminTitle () {
  wp_enqueue_script('admin_title_disable');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'disableAdminTitle');
```

Now, in your js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#title').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

This will set both post and page title input fields with a `disabled` attribute. Hope this helps!

If you want to restrict this script to a particular admin page, wrap the `add_action` hook in a conditional that compares `$_GET['page']`. You can also take advantage of the `$hook` parameter that is available when using `admin_enqueue_scripts` to check for the page. [See here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

**Update::**

WordPress makes it a little tricky to tell between post and page edit screens, but there is a hidden input that you can take advantage of. :) Here's an updated version of the jQuery that will only run on page edit screens:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  //find the hidden post type input, and grab the value
  if($('#post_type').val() === 'page'){
    $('#title').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but, I tried it out and the following error showed:
Warning: Missing argument 2 for wp_register_script()

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto The second argument needs to the be the path to your script... Do you know how to get that? Try refreshing the page to see my updated answer.

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm! But, there is something that I wasn't expecting, it makek even Post-type's Title's readonly, isnt there a way to make just Pages? Thanks again!

Comment: Don't forget that you might want to add some PHP script as well. Since anyone with JS disabled, or FireBug or Google Chrome's inspector will be able to enter a title in there.

Comment: @HenriqueFoletto See my updated answer. It will check to see if the post type is a page, and only disable the title if it's a page edit screen.

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov He's using this in a case where the user is "new to WordPress" so I don't think there is a legitimate concern for someone editing the markup via a web inspector, but I agree that it may be worth it to modify for a non-js situation.

Comment: Yeah, I was just reminding of that - if the users are not going to be tech-savvy then it's fine to go without the additional PHP script.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer. I have to say: It worked out superbly nice, thanks alot for the answer! So kind of you!

Comment: No worries @HenriqueFoletto! Very happy to help!

Comment: Matthew, you can use the [`global $current_screen`](http://www.studiograsshopper.ch/code-snippets/wordpress-current_screen-variable-admin-screens/) to detect what admin page you are and what post type is being shown (if applicable).

Comment: @brasofilo Good call! Just did a little google-search and if you compare against `$current_screen->id` within the enqueue, that will work as well.

Comment: I [always use](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A12615+current_screen) that global :) - Also, using `add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'callback');` you can print scripts directly in the head and targeting only that screen (`/wp-admin/post.php`). Once there, just check for the `global $post; $post->post_type;`.

Answer (score 3):

No need to make a seperate js file. Adding this to your function.php will do the same that Matthew showed.

```
function admin_footer_hook(){
        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if(jQuery('#post_type').val() === 'post'){
    jQuery('#title').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'admin_footer_hook' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This Solution Will disable clicking on the post title and editing it using CSS. CSS targets post type "page" only. It has been tested on Gutenberg visual editor. Users Can still edit title from "Quick Edit".
Add this code to your functions.php file.

```
function disable_title_edit() {
  if(!current_user_can('administrator')){
       if( !current_user_can('administrator')){ ////Only allow Admin
      echo '<style>.post-type-page .edit-post-visual-editor__post-title-wrapper{
       pointer-events: none;
    }</style>'; } }
    }
add_action('admin_head', 'disable_title_edit', 100);
```