# Disable editing page titles for users except admin

Tags: wordpress, user-roles, wordpress-capabilities

How to disable page title editing for users except admin ? they should be able to see page title, but should not be able to edit page title in backend.

```html
function disableAdminTitle () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles )){
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_title_disable');
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'disableAdminTitle');

function admin_footer_hook(){
        ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#title').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer-post.php', 'admin_footer_hook' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
wp_register_script('admin_title_disable', '/path/to/admin_title_disable.js');
function disableAdminTitle () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles )){
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_title_disable');
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'disableAdminTitle');
```

Js Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('#title').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: thanks @rajat.gite, it's working but it has disabled for admin too, admin should be able to edit titles :(, I have updated code in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution mentioned in [Make Wordpress Pages's Titles readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534906/make-wordpress-pagess-titles-readonly) along with `user_can`.

Comment: this will be disabled for admin too ?? @Dakshinamurthy Karra